# Use Generics/Patterns in Java for object mapping

Tags: java, generics, design-patterns, proxy

I have a proxy service which exposes several APIs - each requesting an Object of a specific type and returning an Object of a specific type. Requests come to my ProxyService which are mapped to the format expected by the underlying service:

```
public class ProxyService {
    public ProxyServiceResponse_A performA(ProxyServiceRequest_A request);
    public ProxyServiceResponse_B performB(ProxyServiceRequest_B request);
    public ProxyServiceResponse_C performC(ProxyServiceRequest_C request);
    ...
}

public class ProxiedService {
    public ProxiedServiceResponse_A performA(ProxiedServiceRequest_A request);
    public ProxiedServiceResponse_B performB(ProxiedServiceRequest_B request);
    public ProxiedServiceResponse_C performC(ProxiedServiceRequest_C request);
    ...
}
```

I want to create generic mappers for mapping incoming ProxyService requests to ProxiedService requests:

```
public class MyRequestMapper {
    public ProxiedServiceRequest_A mapRequestA(ProxyServiceRequest_A request);
    ...
}
```

I know of dozer and apache-velocity but I don't want to use those, instead do this on my own. Is there a design pattern or a generic way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You might consider a generic interface.

```
interface RequestMapper<T, U> {
    U mapRequest(T request);
}

class ARequestMapper implements RequestMapper<ProxyServiceRequest_A, ProxiedServiceRequest_A> {
    @Override
    public ProxiedServiceRequest_A mapRequest(ProxyServiceRequest_A request) {
        //TODO
    }
}

class BRequestMapper implements RequestMapper<ProxyServiceRequest_B, ProxiedServiceRequest_B> {
    @Override
    public ProxiedServiceRequest_B mapRequest(ProxyServiceRequest_B request) {
        //TODO
    }
}
```